# IE11: How to check into which zone a URL falls?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

I have applied several internet explorer settings via group policy. Especially a long list of URLs in the "site to zone assignment" setting. However it seems that one URL still falls into the "internet zone" even when assigned to the "trusted zone".

In earlier versions of internet explorer one could easily determine from the status bar into which zone an URL falls. How can this be done via IE11? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: I also agree with Matze.
Even though, Microsoft provide the information in File-Properties.
but it not easy to debug.
If possible I would like to ask Microsoft return this feature back or give some option to selectable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the menu bar, if you go to File->Properties. The properties dialog shows the zone for that page.

Comment: Just found it out by myself. Thanks for replying. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2689449

Comment: Press `Alt + F + R` key

Comment: You can also right-click and go to properties.

Answer (score 4):

This Microsoft created software will allow you to enter a URL and display not only the zone that falls into (including the local computer zone - there are actually four IE zones) but it will show the specific IE settings that would be applied. It's a great tool for diagnosing policy issues:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fdcc/2011/09/22/iezoneanalyzer-v3-5-with-zone-map-viewer/

Answer (score 1):

You can check the zone via powershell:

```
PS C:\> [System.Security.Policy.Zone]::CreateFromUrl('C:\')

SecurityZone
------------
  MyComputer


PS C:\> [System.Security.Policy.Zone]::CreateFromUrl('\\some-computer-name\c$\')

SecurityZone
------------
    Intranet


PS C:\> [System.Security.Policy.Zone]::CreateFromUrl('https://www.google.com/')

SecurityZone
------------
    Internet


PS C:\>
```

Documentation for System.Security.Policy.Zone.CreateFromUrl: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.policy.zone.createfromurl